# Hibernate JPA with @OneToMany mapped to @Any without join table

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

SpringBoot 2.0.1.  I'm trying to setup a generic "Address" object that can be attached to a variety of "AddressableDomainObject" objects.  The below code succeeds in building the Hibernate session, however when I try to retrieve the Company object, mapping issue:

```
MappingException: Foreign key (FKk0e4770oa17lasc49nfp6mfxm:addresses [owner_object_type,owner_object_id])) must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key (contacts [id])
```

What I want for it to do is "select * from addresses where owner_object_id = ? and owner_object_type = 'COMPANY'" to build the list.  And on the Address side, it should "select from companies where id = addresses.owner_object_id" when owner_object_type = 'COMPANY'

Table Definitions

```
create table addresses(
   id bigint,
   owner_object_type varchar(40),
   owner_object_id bigint,
   address ...
)
create table companies(
   id bigint,
   legal_name varchar(80),
   name ...
)
```

Generic Interface:

```
public interface AddressableDomainObject {

    public String getObjectType();
    public long getId();
}
```

package-info.java

```
@AnyMetaDef(
        name = "AddressableDomainObjectMetaDef",
        metaType = "string",
        idType = "long",
        metaValues = {
                @MetaValue(value = "CONTACT", targetEntity = Contact.class),
                @MetaValue(value = "COMPANY", targetEntity = Company.class)                    
        }
)
```

Company.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "companies")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "seq_companies", initialValue = 1)
@DiscriminatorValue("COMPANY")
public class Company implements AddressableDomainObject {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "seq_companies")
    long id;

    String name;
    String legalName;
    String companyType;
    Long parentCompanyId;


    @Override
    public final String getObjectType(){
        return "COMPANY";
    }

    @OneToMany(
        mappedBy = "ownerObject",
        cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    List<Address> addresses;
}
```

Address.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "addresses")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "seq_addresses", initialValue = 1)
public class Address implements UsableDomainObject {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "seq_addresses")
    private long id;

    private String usage;

    private String address;
    private String address2;
    private String city;
    private String state;
    private String postalCode;
    private String country;
    private String gpsCoordinates;
    private String notes;

    @Any(
            metaDef = "AddressableDomainObjectMetaDef",
            metaColumn = @Column(name="owner_object_type")
    )
    @JoinColumn(name = "owner_object_id")
    private AddressableDomainObject ownerObject;
}
```

Comment: Did you try `@Embedded`?

Comment: Embedded just copies the properties of the child into the parent, right?  i.e. it adds the Address fields into the Company object?  If so, that does not work since I need to have 0..n Address objects attached to the company, preferably without a join table

Comment: @JohnP did you solve your problem? I'm facing similar issue

Comment: @GaneshSatpute did you ever find a solution. I'm getting the same issue. I was able to solve the FK issue by removing mappedBy and adding JoinColumn, in this way context loads, but then my collection is always empty.

Comment: @Fabio no, I did not :(. If you do find the solution, please post it here.